# Updating Codemagic Android build status to self-hosted GitLab repository

Tags: gitlab, codemagic

I have self-hosted GitLab repository and I use Codemagic CI.

I have already configured automatic triggering with webhooks in GitLab settings, but after the build is complete, the status is not displayed in the MR tab in GitLab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Codemagic doesn't report build status back to self-hosted repositories. However you can add simple `curl` command in `publishing/scripts` section to report `passed` or `failed` statuses.

```
scripts:
  - # you build commands
    ...
  - name: Build finished successfully
    script: touch ~/.SUCCESS
publishing:
  scripts:
    - name: Report build status
      script: |
        if [ -a "~/.SUCCESS" ] ; then
           # build successful
        else
           # build failed
        fi
```

see also GitLab API doc how to add status check  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/status_checks.html#set-status-of-an-external-status-check

ps: if you use Workflow Editor you can add post-publishing script and use built-in environment variable `CM_BUILD_STEP_STATUS`

Comment: Sad to head that, this mean there is no, pending, or cancel status update.
Any plan to add this in future? other CI (bitrise) got this out of the box ;)